# How can I detect tab focus changes in an android TabLayout?

Tags: java, android

I have a ViewPager set up with a TabLayout at the top. The app is running on a device with physical d-pad directional keys that can be used to move the control focus.

How can I detect when the focus is moved to specific tabs in the TabLayout?
I can see the Tab highlight when the focus is received, but I am unable to find any events that might allow me to detect this.
Also, TabSelected doesn't work, as it doesn't fire until the center key of the d-pad is pressed to "select" the focused tab.

Comment: Have you tried calling `setOnFocusChangeListener()` on the  `View` returned by `getCustomView()` on the `TabLayout.Tab` for each tab?

Comment: I tried adding `tab1.getCustomView().setOnFocusChangeListener` just after doing `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager`, but it gives me a NullPointerException...  I can do things like `tab1.setIcon()`, so I'm sure the Tab itself exists already at that point...

Comment: Oh, right, `getCustomView()` is only if you actually *use* a custom view...  There may not be a supported option for this for the stock tab views.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom view to your tab, and then setOnFocusChangeListener for this view.

Comment: So would I need to recreate the existing tab inner layout in a new custom view, just to get this event?

Comment: So I've created a simple XML layout and assigned it to the Tab as a custom view. I can now use `tab1.getCustomView` and assign an `onFocusChangeListener`. The problem is that the Tab still gets the focus, not my custom view. I also made sure my custom view had `Focusable` property set to true, but still no joy - I get no focus change event trigger.

Comment: did you find a solution so far?